# Scala generic function confusion

Tags: scala, reflection, types, wildcard

I've got a following situation:

Got a method `def f(lst: List[Any])`, which does some transformation of the list and returns result of that transformation (all those `Any`'s are case classes). What I need to accomplish is when the input list is empty, generate a list, containing one element of the correct type and do that transformation with it.

Is it possible to guarantee on a type level, that some case class has a no-arg constructor? If so, what should `Any` be replaced with? If no, what is the best way to accomplish this? Maybe I should just change my method to something like `def f[T](lst: List[T], default: T)`?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note: `f` is a method, not a function. Functions are created with `=>` (which is basically just syntactic sugar for anonymously extending one of the `FunctionN` traits and overriding `apply`), `def` defines methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> def f[A : Zero](lst: List[A]) = {
     |   val xs = if(lst.isEmpty) List(mzero[A]) else lst
     |   xs ++ xs // some transformation
     | }
f: [A](lst: List[A])(implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Zero[A])List[A]

scala> f(List.empty[Int])
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 0)

scala> f(List("hello", "world"))
res2: List[java.lang.String] = List(hello, world, hello, world)
```

If yes, you can refer to [this post](http://missingfaktor.blogspot.in/2011/08/emulating-cs-default-keyword-in-scala.html) I wrote on the subject a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, the type system can't tell you if a class has a default constructor. Remember that case classes don't normally have a default constructor, since no-arg case classes are deprecated. The concept of default constructors isn't so useful with immutable objects. AFAIK there's no reason why there shouldn't be in principle (Scala does support structural types where a type must have a method of a particular name), but it would require a language change. You could check at runtime with reflection, but that's not what you want.

You can however use the type class pattern to force a default value to be in scope. This is conceptually very similar to adding an extra default arguement as suggested in the OP, but using implicits to hide them. It's used heavily in the collections library. missingfaktor's answer using `scalaz.Zero` is a special case of this, but it's dead easy to do in vanilla Scala and for some arbitrary default that isn't necessarily some sort of zero.

```
case class Default[T](default: T)

case class Foo(value: String)
case class Bar(value: Int)

implicit val fooDefault = Default(Foo("I'm a default Foo"))  // note 1
```

Now let's look at an example usage:

```
def firstItem[T](lst: List[T]) (implicit ev: Default[T]) =   // note 2
  if (lst.isEmpty) ev.default else lst.head

val fooList      = List(Foo("cogito"), Foo("ergo"), Foo("sum"))
val emptyFooList = List[Foo]()
val barList      = List(Bar(101), Bar(102))
val emptyBarList = List[Bar]()

firstItem(fooList)                        // Foo("cogito")
firstItem(emptyFooList)                   // Foo("I'm a default Foo")
firstItem(barList)                        // ** error: missing implicit **
```

So we see that this compiles with a `List[Foo]`, but a `List[Bar]` is not accepted because there is no implicit `Default[Bar]` (note 3).

---

note 1: This implicit could be defined on `object Foo` - which would make sure it's in scope if you import the class elsewhere. But it doesn't have to be: you can also define similar implicits for an arbitrary class, `Int`, `String`, whatever (try it).

note 2: This is equal to the sugared version `def firstItem[T: Default](lst: List[T]) =`..., where you summon `ev` with `implicitly[Default[T]]`. Take your pick.

note 3:  We can make it work by simply supplying one:

```
firstItem(barList)(Default(Bar(42)))      // Bar(101)
firstItem(emptyBarList)(Default(Bar(42))) // Bar(42)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do (maybe you can include a few more details), but some advice I can give immediately is if you have a bunch of related cases classes, they should all extend a sealed trait.  Not only will this allow you to have better type safety (no more `Any`), but the compiler will be able to check for in-exhaustive pattern matching.  For example:

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo
case class Baz(y: String) extends Foo
```

Then you can define your function like so

```
def f[T <: Foo](lst: List[Foo], default: T)//...
```

This will allow `list` to contain items of any of the case classes, but require that `default` is the type specified by the type parameter (which is required to be a subtype of `Foo`)